# Learning Measure Theory and Probability Theory

Tags: probability-theory, self-learning

My goal is to do every exercise from the below book

**Athreya, K. B. and Lahiri, S. N. (2006). Measure Theory and Probability Theory**

The issue is I could not find any solution Manual, and since I will be doing self-study verifying my solution would be the best way to confirm that I really learned these topics!

-Is there any Solution Manual Available for this specific book? 
if not Could you share your own solutions?

-In case you have notes homework  from your classes with solutions and examples I would really appreciate if you could send those in my e-mail or share a google drive link. I  promise disclosure ( I just want to learn 100% that stuff and I can't afford to have a teacher)

I will add my e-mail address below in the comments

Comment: my e-mail is xlimitx@yahoo.com

Comment: I dont think that you need the solutions, this book is not so complicate and goes step by step. Everything is straightforward. In any case you can show here, in MSE, what you did to confirm if you did it correctly

Comment: Often advanced undergraduate and graduate texts do not have solution manuals because there isn't much of an incentive to make them. You will probably have to do without one if you come up empty after checking on a few search engines. As Masacroso says, you can always ask for help on MSE.